# Dropping Packets By IP With C++

Tags: c++, windows-7

I'm writing a program in C++ that sniffs packets and compares them to a table by IP address.  I would ike to know how to "Drop A Packet" if it does not meet the criteria that I setup.  Everything is done, the sniffer, the criteria.  I just need to know how to drop the packet...
Windows 7, Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: 100 internets if that makes sense to anyone.

Comment: @Gleno: I just figure a very general question deserves a very general answer.

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to write a software firewall? You need to hook into Windows's networking for that. It's not trivial. You can't just call a function to make packets magically disappear from your entire computer. I suggest using one of the readily available firewalls already out there.

Comment: Can you suggest a firewall written C++ that I can actually play around with the code and will work with Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

In general, packet **sniffers** don't modify the underlying stream, they just observe it.

It sound like what you really want is some sort of transparent proxy.

However, you should post some sample code or more details on what you are doing, since we have no idea how you actually implemented anything, and thus can't offer any suggestions.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware that the sniffer just observes things and thats fine.  But the problem I'm having is dropping what I see.  I know there is WFP but, once again I'm not sure how to attach or insert my code to it.  But I still have to figure out how to drop the packet.  Would a packet shaper do the trick....or do I have to set up an entire firewall situation?